# ¿Cómo paso esto a un array / json?

Tags: php

Tengo esta respuesta de mercado pago:

```
MercadoPago\Plan Object ( [id:protected] => c9538f636c6d47979ac8dc0606b71aa8 [application_fee:protected] => [status:protected] => active [description:protected] => Monthly premium package [external_reference:protected] => [date_created:protected] => 2019-09-03T12:19:15.548-04:00 [last_modified:protected] => 2019-09-03T12:19:15.548-04:00 [auto_recurring:protected] => stdClass Object ( [frequency] => 1 [frequency_type] => months [transaction_amount] => 200 [currency_id]
=> ARS [repetitions] => [debit_date] => [free_trial] => stdClass Object ( [frequency] => [frequency_type] => ) ) [live_mode:protected]
=> 1 [setup_fee:protected] => [metadata:protected] => [_last:protected] => MercadoPago\Plan Object ( [id:protected] => c9538f636c6d47979ac8dc0606b71aa8 [application_fee:protected] => [status:protected] => active [description:protected] => Monthly premium package [external_reference:protected] => [date_created:protected] => 2019-09-03T12:19:15.548-04:00 [last_modified:protected] => 2019-09-03T12:19:15.548-04:00 [auto_recurring:protected] => stdClass Object ( [frequency] => 1 [frequency_type] => months [transaction_amount] => 200 [currency_id]
=> ARS [repetitions] => [debit_date] => [free_trial] => stdClass Object ( [frequency] => [frequency_type] => ) ) [live_mode:protected]
=> 1 [setup_fee:protected] => [metadata:protected] => [_last:protected] => [error:protected] => [_pagination_params:protected] => [_empty:protected] => ) [error:protected] => [_pagination_params:protected] => [_empty:protected] => )
```

Que lo obtuve desde `PHP`, con el ejemplo

```
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
 require_once 'mercadopago/autoload.php';

  MercadoPago\SDK::setClientId('234');
  MercadoPago\SDK::setClientSecret('1234');

  $plan = new MercadoPago\Plan();
  $plan->description = "Monthly premium package";
  $plan->auto_recurring = array(
    "frequency" => 1,
    "frequency_type" => "months",
    "transaction_amount" => 200
  );
  $plan->save();

  print_r($plan);
```

Mi pregunta es, como hago para que este `object` lo pueda pasar a `json/array` tratable, lo intento solucionar por mis propios medios pero veo que no puedo solucionarlo

Aca dejo un print de pantalla para que vean como se expresa en el navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: cambiado el `print_r($plan);`  por un `echo json_encode($plan,true);`

Comment: Nop, pues me agarra todo y convierte como string de unico valor

Comment: @GusGeek, lo que dice Bryro es correcto, quiza tu navegador no reconoce los json, intenta hacerlo sin el `echo`, osea algo asi: `return json_encode($plan);` o simplemente `var_dump(json_encode($plan))`

Comment: El objeto ya es tratable o ¿a qué te refieres con tratable?

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza **`JSON_ENCODE`** sobre una variable para que ésta obtenga el formato **`JSON`**.

```
return json_encode($plan);
```

Comment: `return` ?? si no es una funcion :v, por lo menos intenta esponder de una forma adecuada!

Comment: Tranqui gente, no se alarmen.

Comment: Es uno de sus ejemplo de uso, se puede utilizar en un print_r o almacenarlo en una variable... el caso es que desea pasar el array a json

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude resolver.

El Script para que me de la respuesta, esta orientada a objetos.

Por tal, el var_dump / print_r me pueden orientar en como se llama cada objeto, obtenerlo, identificarlo y usarlo. ¿Como puedo usarlo?, bueno, jSon y Array no serviran en este caso. Simplemente se orienta a Objetos.

Si respuesta del script es

> MercadoPago\Plan Object ( [id:protected] =>
>   c9538f636c6d47979ac8dc0606b71aa8 [application_fee:protected] =>
>   [status:protected] =>...

entonces se maneja con

```
$plan->id;
$plan->application_fee;
$plan->status;
```